# Comparison of languages by usage type?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, comparison

Does anyone know of a good place to go find comparisons of programming languages by the intended platform/usage?  Basically, what I want to know, is of the more popular languages, which ones are meant for high level application development, low level system development, mobile development, web, etc.  If there's a good listing out there already, I'm not finding it so far.  Does anyone know of a place that would have this?  Thanks.

Comment: Finally found the article I was looking for <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages">here</a>. This shows me the intended use that I want, and I have other charts for other <a href="http://jvoegele.com/software/langcomp.html">comparisons</a> I need. Thanks for the time everyone.

Comment: I'd take this list with a grain of salt.  It's not always easy to say what a language is "intended" for, let alone how its actual usage evolves in practice.  Consider that this list says that C++ is a "application, systems" language, whereas C# is a "applications, web language".  And yet, [one of the largest web applications on Earth](http://www.google.com "Google") uses a considerable amount of C++.  Also, Javascript (a "client-side web" language), is finding a niche in [server-side programming](http://nodejs.org/ "node.js") as well.  It also claims Lisp is a "text processing" language.

Comment: @Charles Salvia - That's true, but I only need the list for a meeting with uppeer management.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [the right tool](http://therighttool.hammerprinciple.com) website.

The principle : the site gives a list of languages, and a list of statements. Anyone can give his opinion on whether the statement applies to the languages they are familiar with. The results are browsable by languages and by statements.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_category) has a pretty awesome categorical list of languages.

Comment: That's a great list, but i'm more looking for platform appropriateness: desktop, web, system level, cloud, etc.